# PHP load CSV without filename

Tags: php, csv

I am in index.php, and at the same directory level I have a CSV file which I load using

```
$reader = new CSV\CSVReader('mycsv.csv');
```

This is the only CSV in the folder.  After it is read, I want to delete it from my FTP and replace it with a different CSV.  However, if possible, I don't want to have to edit the PHP file each time to change the filename.

Knowing that the root will only ever have one CSV file in it at any time, is there any way to load this without using the filename?

Comment: did you try in any way to check what are the contents of that directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get all the files with a .csv extension using [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). Then just use the first file in the result array since there's only one. Something like this:

```
$csvFiles = glob('*.csv');
if (!count($csvFiles)) die('Error: No CSV file to read');
$reader = new CSV\CSVReader($csvFiles[0]);

// Optionally, if you want to automatically delete the file:
unlink($csvFiles[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$files = scandir('/path/to/directory');
$filename = $files[2]; // avoid dots elements
```